# Using moment of intertia to shortest travel time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

> Consider a ball and a cylinder with mass $m$, half diameter $r$ and a moment of inertia, around the axis of rotation $I$. Define $I^*=\frac{I}{mr^2}$. Determine $I^*$ for a hollow ball and a massive cylinder with a half inner diameter $a$ and a half outside diameter $R$. Give the answer in $b=\frac{a}{R}$

I thought: For a hollow ball, the moment of inertia is equal to $I=\frac{2}{3}mr^2$, hence $I^*=2/3$. For the massive cylinder it is equal to $I=\frac{1}{2}mr^2$. Hence, $I^*=\frac{1}{2}$. However, I am asked to give the answer in $b=\frac{a}{R}$ and I am not particullary sure what they mean with that. Especially considering the next question asks me what happens if $a\to 0$ and $a \to R$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has some inconsistencies and the first half of the question doesn't match up with the second half, consider then also want you to answer what happens if a→0 and a→R. I can assume that the question wants you to consider a shell and a cylinder with a thickness.
(Also, they have given outer and inner radii, so that makes sense)
You are expected to show that when a→0 the MoI is the same as that of a solid sphere/cylinder and when a→R it's that of the hollow ones.

See:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia